# Add more paths to attach token for any request

Tags: azure

Following this [MS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code#acquire-a-token) for sending in token when requesting Azure Graph. I'd like to add more path for the `MSAL Interceptor` to send in token for my Static Web App (SWA) has integrated API. Project structure:

```
|--api (folder contains Azure Functions, each in its own folder, i.e AF1, AF2)
|
|--src (standard Angular structure)
```

app.module.ts, adding one entry inside `new Map` getting redirected back without hitting API

```
MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {...},
      cache: {...}
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {scopes: ['user.read']}
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, 
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
          ['/api/AF1', ['api://custom api consent']]    // but never hit the API AF1
      ])
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [MS Doc](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-docs/msal-interceptor.md) and playing around in Portal, solution:

`['/api/*', ['offline_access']]`

This is not an ideal approach as Msal Interceptor only attaches token. To attach additional items needs to build our own, for example using Angular's `HttpInterceptor`.